# Jquery MouseOver for each child div

Tags: php, jquery, mouseover

This is a part of my jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var timer, imgsrc, cnt = 1;
$('.post-image img').bind('mouseover', function() {
// if there is no timer
if (!timer) {
var $t = $(this);
var site = $(this).next('.sourcesite').val(); //$(this)>("sourcesite").html();
var dd = $(this).children('div.dd'); //$(this)>("dd"); 
// get the image src
imgsrc = $t.attr('src') //;.replace('default.jpg',''); 
imgReverse = imgsrc.split("").reverse().join(""); // get the image src
// var site="al";
if (site == 'al') {
imgSlash = imgReverse.indexOf('/');
imgDot = imgReverse.indexOf('.');
imgID1 = imgReverse.substr(imgDot + 1, imgSlash - imgDot - 1);
imgID = imgID1.split("").reverse().join("");
} /*getting image name finished for "al"*/
if (site == 'bg') {
imgSplitDot = imgReverse.split('.');
imgID = imgSplitDot[1];
}
dd.html(site);
// get the image src
imgsrc = $t.attr('src').replace(imgID + '.jpg', '');
// start a new timer
timer = setInterval(function() {
// periodically change the src
$t.attr('src', imgsrc + cnt + ".jpg");
// and adjust the counter
cnt = (cnt + 1); //% 3; // 0, 1, 2
if (cnt == 21) {
cnt = 1;
}
}, 700); // <- 1000ms = 1s
}
}).bind('mouseout', function() {
// stop rotation
if (timer) {
clearInterval(timer);
timer = null;
cnt = 0;
}
// set the default img
$(this).attr('src', imgsrc + imgID + '.jpg');
});
});​
```

And This is my HTML:

```
<div class="post-image">
<a class="" href="index2.php?vid=php_id&name=name" title="php_name">
<img width="180" height="135" src="php_imgsource" class="attachment" alt="" title=""/>
</a>
<div class="sourcesite">php_sourcesite</div>
<div class="dd">0</div>
</div>
```

On mouseover over a `div`, the image will change one by one.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YkuXt/1/

But there are different image srcs in my page, so I use an if in this jquery code. I am type source name in the `<div class="sourcesite"></div>` by php code and I want get sourcesite value by jquery and use a if like in the sample. If it is "al" some code part will work but if it is "bg" other part will work. Because image source are different. And there is sample of image sources:

- Sample 1: [samplesites.com/img/012345677.1.jpg](http://samplesites.com/img/012345677.1.jpg)
- Sample 2: [samplesites.com/img/5.jpg](http://samplesites.com/img/012345677.1.jpg)

I need to get image names such as: "1" and "5". After I found 1 I will increment it 1-by-1 by a timer and Image will be changed on mouseover.

Thanks, All.

Comment: please format your code properly. Also, since we're talking javascript, you'll want to post your rendered HTML, not the PHP stuff.

Comment: ok plz wait . I am formating it sorry

Comment: I formated it. This is ok now?

Comment: @metin: take a read of the [formatting/mark-down editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for a look at how to format with the mark-down syntax. But kudos for trying, and being willing to try further! =)